# How to train a custom embedding?

Tags: autoencoders, word-embeddings, embeddings

I have data with a lot of categorical features. The cardinality of some of these features is quite big (>100), so I want to avoid using one-hot encoding. The idea is to use an embedding.

The problem here is that I do not quite understand how I can learn an embedding for my problem domain. There are these pre-trained embeddings like Word2Vec, but suppose the goal is to create a totally new embedding.

What I have done so far is to encode my features as numeric values. For example, if one of the features is a type of vehicle, then the conversion looks like this:

```
car      --> 1
train    --> 2
boat     --> 3
aircraft --> 4
...
rocket   --> 100
```

Each of these integers i corresponds to a 100-dimensional one-hot vector, where the i-th entry is a 1 and the rest is zero. To reduce the dimensionality of the input to, let's say, 5, an embedding is a matrix of size 100 x 5, which is randomly initialized at first. So when I put a car (1) into the embedding layer, it returns a 5-dimensional (random) vector. To give meaning to these embeddings, I have to adjust the the weights inside the matrix with respect to something like a target variable. But where do I get it from, so that the embedding represents something meaningful?

A lot of models seem to include the embeddings as part of their model, but as far as I can tell, this does not work for me. If it helps, I try to use the embedded variable in combination with other numeric variables as input for an autoencoder, but this model minimizes the loss between the output of the embedding layer and their respective reconstruction.

I would be grateful for any help!

EDIT:

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 2)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)           (None, 2, 5)         500         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 2, 2)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 2, 7)         0           embedding[0][0]                  
                                                                 input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                     (None, 10)           720         concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector (RepeatVector)    (None, 2, 10)        0           lstm[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                   (None, 2, 10)        840         repeat_vector[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistribut (None, 2, 7)         77          lstm_1[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,137
Trainable params: 2,137
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Because you've added the [tag:autoencoder] tag, I assume you're using a neural network. Modern neural network libraries take care of the details for you: just use an embedding layer and train the model using backprop. Backprop updates the weights for you, in the usual way as for any other neural network weights/biases.

Comment: The embedding (from word2vec or wherever else) are learned so that similar things agave similar embeddings. What evidence can you use to inform a model that two things are similar, so you can learn the embeddings?

Comment: @Sycorax: You are right, I do. I have added a minimal model example in my post. As you can see there, I concatenate the embedding output of size 5 with 2 numerical features, so 7 features in total. The autoencoder is trained to minimize the loss between the concat-layer and the output (shape of None, 2, 7). The minimization of any loss between those two tensors does NOT include the embedding, therefore I will not update the weights in the embedding layer. That the reason why I resorted to train the embedding separately. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What makes you think the embedding is not being updated? The weights are trainable just like every other part of the model.

Comment: @Sycorax: I simply cannot train the model this way. Suppose the measure for optimizing is MSE. It is defined only for tensors of the same shape. So if I included the embedding layer to my model, my (combined) inputs were of shape (None, 2, 3) and the output of shape (None, 2, 7). And the shape of the output is determined by the concat-layer for reasons of symmetry of the autoencoder.

Comment: I basically needed a kind of reverse-Embedding layer to make this work.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to have conformable shapes. Word embeddings don't go directly from the embedding vector to predicting the vocabulary; instead, they predict the surrounding words, or using the context words to predict the middle word. You could do something similar by predicting the category and the numerical information given the output of concatenate. An easy way to do this is to have 2 outputs, 1 that predicts the input category and 1 that predicts the numerical data.

Comment: @Sycorax: I'm afraid I am not able to follow you. Would you be so kind an give a rough outline of the model architecture? Like input_numerical + input_embedding --> concat

Comment: `input_numerical + input_embedding --> concat --> z` and `z --> dense1 --> output1` and `z --> dense2 --> output2`. Then use `output1` to predict category and `output2` to predict the numerical data.